# UnityAdsIntegration.cs(54,11): error CS1061

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

UnityAdsIntegration.cs(54,11): error CS1061: 'ShowOptions' does not contain a definition for 'resultCallback' and no accessible extension method 'resultCallback' accepting a first argument of type 'ShowOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y17jE.png)

Comment: Please add the contents of the `UnityAdsIntegration.cs` file as code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Error CS1061 is raised when you try to call a nonexistent method or access a nonexistent member.

You can refer to [here](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206193836-What-is-CS1061-).

The following example demonstrates an attempt to call the SayGoodbye method on an object of type Class1. As we can see the type Class1 does not contain the definition of SayGoodbye.

[image]

The error message for this example is as follows:

```
 error CS1061: Type `Class1’ does not contain a definition for `SayGoodbye’ and no extension method `SayGoodbye’ of type `Class1’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Solution:

You need to ensure that methods and class members exist and are accessed from the correct location in order to resolve CS1061 errors.

[image]

Original address: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206193836-What-is-CS1061-